# Python Image reading

Tags: image-processing, python-3.x, ocr

Is it possible to read the text on a gif with python? I don't think it is but if it is if you could show me how to do it that would be great. Heres what I've been trying to do

```
def getContents(url):
    x = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()# would add decode, but it gives errors 
    return x
```

doing "getContents(gif)" returns weird characters, that look like bytes "\x00" etc. Not sure if their is anything in python that can read them. I apologize if my description is too vague, but its the best I can describe it the problem is open a gif then reading it or opening a jpg and reading it would give read text that's returned.

Answer (score 2):

This is called OCR. There are a number of such libraries, give tesseract a try:
http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/